# Unix command to copy last line of file to another file

Tags: file, unix, command

Please provide a command to append an existing file by taking a last line of another file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
tail -n 1 $file1 >> $file2
```

Though most systems also support

```
tail -1 $file1 >> $file2
```

Comment: `tail -n 1` is correct POSIX syntax, `tail -1` should be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

```
tail $file1 -n 1 >> $file2
```

Or,

```
tail -1 $file1 >> $file2
```

If you want it to work with `sudo`:

```
tail -1 $file1 | tee -a $file2
```